# How to use the code plugin with popcornjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, youtube, popcornjs

I am doing my first steps with Popcornjs and I am trying to use the [code plugin](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/plugins/#Code) but not sure how to do it.

I followed [this](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/plugins/#Code) example, and got the video to play, but I can not use the plugin.

Index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/popcornjs/popcorn.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/popcornjs/wrappers/common/popcorn._MediaElementProto.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/popcornjs/wrappers/youtube/popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/popcornjs/plugins/code/popcorn.code.js"></script>
```

Media.js

```
$scope.player = Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement( "#media-player" );
$scope.player.src = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaN2Y2-wNSs";
```

// the following lines fail

```
//$scope.player.code({
//    start: Popcorn.util.toSeconds( 2 ),
//    onStart: function () {
//        console.log( "I am here" );
//    }
//});
```

// Object # has no method 'code'

How do I use the plugin?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because you didn't actually wind up creating a popcorn instance. The naming conventions behind the wrappers are somewhat confusing and should probably be changed.

When you created a new HTMLYouTubeVideoElement object that will just control basic player interactions with the YouTube video. To create a Popcorn instance with that, you simply pass that object to Popcorn. Your code should wind up being something like the following:

```
$scope.player = new Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement( "#media-player" );
$scope.player.src = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaN2Y2-wNSs";
$scope.player = new Popcorn( $scope.player );

$scope.player.code({
  start: Popcorn.util.toSeconds( 2 ),
  onStart: function () {
      console.log( "I am here" );
  }
});
```

That will create a new HTMLYouTubeVideoElement object and then pass it to Popcorn and create a Popcorn instance. Popcorn instances are needed to add new events to the video.

Comment: Thanks!. Where I can find the updated docs/apis? I could not find any mention of HTMLYouTubeVideoElement in popcornjs.

Comment: Sadly they aren't documented at all to the best of my knowledge. We don't have much man power existing or time to get them redone/updated.

I'd encourage you to ask any questions you might have on the mailing list at https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/community-popcorn

Answer (score 0):

To integrated 3rd party libraries into Angular you need to create a directive. Anything having to do with DOM requires you to create a directive. Once you've created a directive, you'll do these actions on the element inside the `link` function of the directive. The link function happens after Angular Compiles your code, you can kind of think of it like jQuery's `document.ready` except it's at the element level.

```
myapp.directive('popcornPlayer', function(){
  return:{
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes){
      var player = Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement(element);
      player.src = attributes.src;
      player.code( /* stuff */ );
    }
  }
});
```

Now you could do something like:

```
<popcorn-player src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaN2Y2-wNSs"></popcorn-player>
```

And kablamo! Magic. You'll also probably want to use `attributes.$observe` to make it truly angular magical.

Comment: Nop, Still:
TypeError: Object #<HTMLYouTubeVideoElement> has no method 'code'
    at <server>/scripts/directives/media-player.js:14:28

Comment: Did you get `popcorn-complete` from http://popcornjs.org/download or just popcorn? Because popcorn doesn't include the Code plugin by default.